# Implementing C#/.NET gRPC Healthcheck in kubernetes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes, grpc

## Goal

I want to add a healthcheck to a .NET microservice using the gRPC [health probe protocol](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe).

The microservice is nothing more than the `Greeter` service created with the `dotnet new grpc` template. I've gotten this to run and build locally, directly with Docker, and finally on my development K8s cluster.

## Problem

Following [this post](https://codevalue.com/grpc-health-checks-with-net-core-kubernetes/) and others, I have added the NuGet package to the project, and mapped the endpoint just like with the greeter service; however, the liveness/readiness probes fail due to timeout. I'm new to C#/.NET, so I expect that i've made a mistake in that area, but it is possible that the problem is in the kubernetes resources, too.

## Code

### Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Grpc.HealthCheck;

namespace Company.Project.GRPC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();
            services.AddSingleton<HealthServiceImpl>(); // <-- makes sense to me generally though the details are hazy 
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                // Healthcheck services
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<HealthServiceImpl>(); // <-- what besides this is needed?
                
                // App gRPC services
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
                });
            });

        }
    }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;

namespace Company.Project.GRPC
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            
        }

        // Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
        // For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682
       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    // Setup a HTTP/2 endpoint without TLS.
                    // TODO: Review security. May in fact be ok as an internal-only service
                    // options.ListenLocalhost(5000, o => o.Protocols = 
                    //     HttpProtocols.Http2);
                    options.Listen( System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 5000);
                    options.Listen( System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 50051);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

            });
    }
}
```

### Deployment.yaml

```yaml
...
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
            - containerPort: 50051
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/grpc_health_probe
                - -addr=:50051
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/grpc_health_probe
                - -addr=:50051   # <-- doesn't matter which port I use
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 1
```

## Behavior

When I tail the logs for this pod, I see the server start up just fine, but then get killed after the liveness probe fails. The pod Events shows: `Container myservice failed liveness probe, will be restarted`

The probe client is the official one distributed from the link at the top. I've checked that the file is there, and that it can be executed as instructed.

I don't need any functionality beyond the basic `Check` that the server is reachable and running, so I *believe* that the step of subclassing `HealthCheckImpl` that is included in the post I referenced is superfluous.

What do I need to do/understand to get a working healthcheck on this simple service?